# Flutter could not update time stamp for gc.properties

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am beginner and don't understand yet how gradle works on flutter.  Last time the code run it was fine, but when I rerun it a gradle error happen. Anyway I don't change any gradle file, all I do is just modifiying my dart file and add some plugin in pubspec.yaml

Thank you

Things I've done :
`flutter clean`

````
Launching lib/main.dart on LUNA V55 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              7.9s
Resolving dependencies...                                               
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/Users/ngademint/Documents/firecek/firecek_mobile_backoffice/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:properties

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

INTERNAL__CHECKED_MINIMUM_PLUGIN_VERSIONS: true
allprojects: [project ':app']
android: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension_Decorated@69b7e7dc
androidDependencies: task ':app:androidDependencies'
ant: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder@1dded2de
antBuilderFactory: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilderFactory@5e62e49c
archivesBaseName: app
artifacts: validateSigningProfile: task ':app:validateSigningProfile'
validateSigningRelease: task ':app:validateSigningRelease'
version: unspecified
writeDebugApplicationId: task ':app:writeDebugApplicationId'
writeProfileApplicationId: task ':app:writeProfileApplicationId'
writeReleaseApplicationId: task ':app:writeReleaseApplicationId'
1 actionable task: 1 executed


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not update time stamp for /Users/ngademint/Documents/firecek/firecek_mobile_backoffice/android/.gradle/4.10.2/gc.properties

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: /Users/ngademint/Documents/firecek/firecek_mobile_backoffice/android/gradlew app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm I just solve it by removing gc.properties in `<project>/android/.gradle/4.10.2/` then rerun it. Works like a charm

Comment: For me, I removed `.gralde` folder in the project. `~/project/$ sudo rm -rf .gradle`